# Best Practices When Using CoreBluetooth Framework

Tags: objective-c, iphone, oop, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Lately I have been playing around with the bluetooth framework and grew a strong enough knowledge to start building an application. The only problem is that all the examples I found and all the practice I have made consist in putting the core bluetooth core code inside the same file as the UIView with which the user is interacting.

I would like my future application to have multiple views in which the BLE scan occurs on the background. I initially thought about creating an object with a name similar to `bleDeviceFinder` and pass this object through each view. However, after thinking about it I realised that if I want something to happen in the current view I need the function `didDiscoverPeripheral` to have direct access to the `UIView` objects which it is supposed to affect.

I know it is probably a stupid question, what would be the best way to do so? I was thinking maybe to set and alert and subscribe every view to that alert; is this a good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quasi singleton BTLEManager that you pass around in the app. It sends NSNotifications for events like discovery, and your ViewControllers observe these notifications. The truth (i.e. list of discovered devices) stays in BTLEManager. Once a viewController has received such a notification it asks the BTLEManager for the list of current devices and then the viewController changes your views accordingly. The Views should never talk to the BTLEManager directly.

That's how I would do it.